# Custom HTTP header missing

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http-headers

I'm using a third party service that provides a webhook which POSTs some data on a provided URL upon change of resources on the system.
For security purposes the request should include a custom header (`X_SOLVE360_HMAC_SHA256`) which provides an encrypted token we can use to auth the request (in place of a CSRF token).

Now my problem is that the custom header seems to be missing in the request we receive.
I'm using Laravel v8 and `$request->header()`, which should return all headers, does not include the header we need. Actually it seems it is missing *any* custom headers...
I tried also the vanilla PHP `getallheaders()` or `apache_request_headers()` functions, but the result is the same, only standard headers: `Host`, `Content-Length`, `Accept-encoding`, `User-Agent`, `Content-Type`.
Also the `$_SERVER` super global does not contain what we look for.

I was wondering, is there a PHP or Apache setting that would filter out non standard headers? We are running our app on a VPS on Dreamhost, with PHP v7.4.

Any suggestion or pointer would be helpful.

---

**Edit:**

As I mentioned in the comments, a POST - to our server - from my local computer via Postman, with the same headers of the webhook, works just fine.

Also, the `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # ensure HTTPS before laravel
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No, nothing will be filtered out. Maybe you have some proxy in between? You may try a simple webhook from guthub which also sends a HMAC header.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I can confirm (I used https://requestbin.com) the request does include the expected header. Dreamhost said there is no proxy in between. Any Laravel configuration might be removing non standard headers maybe?

Comment: To debug further, try to test a plain PHP file outputting all headers without Laravel to make ensure nothing other is involved. If it is missing here, try another vhost or server to make sure no middleware removes it.

Comment: Now this is odd: if I POST to our server via Postman with the same headers from the webhook the app sees all the headers, including the one I need... Puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Apache v2.4 ignores headers with underscores, therefore Apache is the culprit here...

Ref https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html

> Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via header injection. Header names containing invalid characters (including underscores) are no longer converted to environment variables. Environment Variables in Apache has some pointers on how to work around broken legacy clients which require such headers. (This affects all modules which use these environment variables.)